# Auto-Populate phone as formatted

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, validation

I want my phone field to be auto-populated as below after record is saved.
+XX (XXX) XXX-XXXX

I've tried regex to format. But, it's working only if I enter a formatted phone number. Can someone help me how to format the phone upon saving the record... The regex function I used is...

```
^((\\+)(\\d{2})?\\s?\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s?\\d{3}\\-\\d{4})?$
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

There are example of Phone Validation Rules including REGEX in the Formulas Guidebook.

For more reference: https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_useful_validation_formulas.pdf